# Using espresso, how can I decide which view action to use according to displayed view?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a form that displays one component at a time, it may be: EditText, Spinner, ListView, or something else according to some rules.

And each component has a different test code.

Using Espresso, how can I check which component is displayed and do its action?

**pseudo code**

```
if( ask to enter the number ){
    onView(withId(R.id.et_number)).perform(replaceText("12345"));
}else if(ask to select my country){
     onView(withRecyclerView(R.id.rv_country).atPosition(0)).perform(click());
}
```

What is the best way to implement this case? And if I have to create my custom matcher, how is the implementation for this case?

I would be grateful to anyone who gives me a simple example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something similar before. What I did was to check if a element was displayed inside a try and catch the exception.
Try this:

```
try { // supposing et_number is displayed
  onView(withId(R.id.et_number)).check.matches(isCompletelyDisplayed())); // will throw an exception if its not displayed
    onView(withId(R.id.et_number)).perform(replaceText("12345"));
} catch (Exception e) { // et_number is not displayed
    onView(withRecyclerView(R.id.rv_country).atPosition(0)).perform(click());
}
```